# The transparent div is over white background div which contains a button. How to add hover effect?

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow, transparent

A transparent div is over another div which is not transparent. Below is the CSS code for your reference.

```
html {
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
}
body {
margin: 0;
}
.parent {
display: block;
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
background-color: transparent;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

**HTML code**

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="parent"></div>
<button onclick="alert('Successful');">Click me!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**Now how can I click that button. I don't want to remove that transparent div because it plays an important role in my actual project. Is it possible to click that button? Not just button I want to make the div behind that accessible.**

**You might recommend me to use z-index CSS property. But I want it to be behind the transparent div. Or you might recommend me to use CSS pointer-events: none property for parent div. But I want pointer-events enabled for it and also for the div behind that.**

**Edit**
Here is the URL to my actual issue. https://minisoftmaxsol.000webhostapp.com/index.html. In that webpage you can find a menu (white div with black shadow) which can be moved with a finger. Everything looks good. But the issue is mouse events not working for the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

there is a CSS Property that affects any element such that mouse doesn't work on the element. So, if you add the css property to the parent element, it would lose the ability to use the mouse, hence it will always click the button. Here's the CSS:

```
.parent{
    /*
      old css
    */
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Warning: If you set this property, mouse would never be able to click the parent element or select any text in the parent element.

Hope you find it useful! ;-) Good Luck!

EDIT>> Let me tell you that tweaking with z-index won't work here because z-index can only be applied on the elements which have the `position` property set to fixed, absolute or sticky.

Comment: about z-index, you forgot position: relative.

Comment: z-index set on 1 and position relative on button would do it. But one again, it would cause button putted on .parent. It depends on what needs to be done.

Comment: @IzabelaFurdzik You're right, actually I wasn't sure about the `position: relative`, so I didn't mentions it. Thanks for correcting me! (I will make an edit to my answer) Now its clear that z-index set to 1 and position relative on button would work well!

Comment: @Satyam Mishra But mouse events not working on parent div :(

Comment: Yes, you're right, and I already told you about this (in the warning), @HEMANTH ABHIRAM SOMARAJU. That's the drawback. You can try setting the position relative, as the majority of answers and comments tell you.

Comment: Have you saw this https://minisoftmaxsol.000webhostapp.com/index.html

Answer (score -2):

I had the same type of issue in my previous projects,

Here is a fiddle I made [JSFIDDLE][1].

The trick is to wrap the button in a `position:relative` property!

Here is what I did:

```css
html {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
    }
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    .controller {
      position: relative;
    }

    .parent {
      display: block;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      background-color: transparent;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
      position: absolute;
      cursor: pointer;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="controller">
      <div class="parent"></div>
      <button class="button-style" onclick="alert('Successful');">
        Click me!
      </button>
    </div>
  </body>
```

The position relative will now serve as a small hole that the user can access the button with!
[1]: https://codesandbox.io/s/transparent-div-oukpk

Comment: Thanks let me check.

Comment: I'm very sorry, I will try to be a bit explanative !

Comment: @Aadhit Shanmugam First of all I appreciate you for trying to help me. You had solved ½ of my issue. Everything looks good. Both the transparent div and button are accessible. But the remaining issue is button is being displayed above the transparent div. I want to make transparent div to be displayed above the button.

Comment: You have to be a bit more specific so that I can help you out!